# Adding packages to memgraph transformation

Tags: python, avro, confluent-schema-registry, memgraphdb

I am writing a memgraph transformation in python.

When I import modules such as "requests" or "networkx", the transformation works as expected.

I have avro data w/ schema registry, so I need to deserialize it. I followed the memgraph example here: https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/2.3.0/import-data/kafka/avro#deserialization

When I save the transformation with those imports, I receive the error:

```
[Error] Unable to load module "/memgraph/internal_modules/test_try_plz.py";
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/memgraph/internal_modules/test_try_plz.py", line 4,
in <module> from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient ModuleNotFoundError:
No module named 'confluent_kafka' . For more details, visit https://memgr.ph/modules.
```

How can I update my transform or memgraph instance to include the confluent_kafka module?

The link provided in the answer did not provide any leads, at least to me.

Comment: Where does this code actually run? You are not about to use `pip install`?

Comment: Also, very strange they don't use `fastavro` directly. What if you don't have a running Schema Registry server, but still want to use Avro?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not entirely sure where it runs within memgraphdb. At the time of the question it was not clear to me how to add any additional dependencies.

I imagine that this would all work w/ just `fastavro`, but it is indeed a bit strange that the example presupposes a confluent "dependency"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add python dependencies to memgraph in memgraph cloud (free trial at least..)

Instead, create your own docker image and use that, e.g.,

```
FROM memgraph/memgraph:2.5.2

USER root

# Install Python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-dev \
    && pip3 install -U pip

# Install pip packages
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the local query modules
COPY transformations/ /usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules
COPY procedures/ /usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules

USER memgraph
```

And my requirements.txt, all of which are required for a transformation leveraging the confluent schema-registry/avro packages:

```
confluent_kafka==2.0.2
fastavro==1.7.1
requests==2.28.2
```